# cPanel Account Login - WHMCS

Tags: php, hook, whmcs

Up to version 8.4.1 I was able to use this code in the hook folder.

```
<?php

use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;

add_hook('ClientAreaPrimarySidebar', 1, function(MenuItem $primarySidebar)
{

$service = Menu::context('service');    
$domain = $service->domain;
$servertype = $service->product->servertype;

# Not cPanel, no links added
   if ($servertype!="cpanel"){
       return;
   }

   if (!is_null($primarySidebar->getChild('Service Details Actions'))) {
            $primarySidebar->getChild('Service Details Actions')
                           ->getChild('Login to cPanel')
                           ->setUri('http://'.$domain.'/cpanel');
            $primarySidebar->getChild('Service Details Actions')
                           ->getChild('Login to Webmail')
                           ->setUri('http://'.$domain.'/webmail');
   }

});
```

In version 8.5.1 it stopped working.

say this message:

> Error: Call to a member function setUri() on null in
> /home/.../.../includes/hooks/cpanel_login.php:20 Stack trace:
> #0 /home/..../..../vendor/whmcs/whmcs-foundation/lib/Hook/Manager.php(0):
> WHMCS\Utility\SafeInclude::{closure}(Object(WHMCS\View\Menu\Item))
> #1 /home/..../..../vendor/illuminate/support/Facades/Facade.php(261): WHMCS\Hook\Manager->run('ClientAreaPrima...', Array, true)
> #2 /home/..../..../includes/functions.php(0): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('run', Array)
> #3 /home/..../..../vendor/whmcs/whmcs-foundation/lib/ClientArea.php(0):
> run_hook('ClientAreaPrima...', Array, true)
> #4 /home/..../..../vendor/whmcs/whmcs-foundation/lib/ClientArea.php(0):
> WHMCS\ClientArea->outputWithoutExit()
> #5 /home/..../..../vendor/whmcs/whmcs-foundation/lib/Http/Message/AbstractViewableResponse.php(0):
> WHMCS\ClientArea->getOutputContent()
> #6 /home/..../..../vendor/laminas/laminas-httphandlerrunner/src/Emitter/SapiEmitter.php(41):
> WHMCS\Http\Message\AbstractViewableResponse->getBody()
> #7 /home/..../..../vendor/laminas/laminas-httphandlerrunner/src/Emitter/SapiEmitter.php(31):
> Laminas\HttpHandlerRunner\Emitter\SapiEmitter->emitBody(Object(WHMCS\ClientArea))
> #8 /home/..../..../clientarea.php(0): Laminas\HttpHandlerRunner\Emitter\SapiEmitter->emit(Object(WHMCS\ClientArea))
> #9 {main}

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `setUri()` on `null`.

You're only checking if there's a sidebar element called "Service Details Actions" - but if either "Service Details Actions", "Login to cPanel" or "Login to Webmail" doesn't exist, you're trying to set a uri for a sidebare child element that doesn't exist.

This most likely has something to do with WHMCS changing how menuitems worked in 8.4.1: https://docs.whmcs.com/Changelog:WHMCS_V8.4#Maintenance_4

> CORE-17437 - Prevent declaration error related to Menu items
> Also known as: CORE-17436

New names are "cpanel" and "webmail" instead of "Login to cPanel" and "Login to Webmail".
To avoid exceptions being thrown, you should check if the menuitem exists.